# MPAndroidChart Combined Chart (Bar & Scatter) with Marker Working only on Scatter Graph points

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I m using MPAndroidChart Combined Chart to display a Bar & Scatter chart. On click on points of Scatter Graph i m showing a custom marker which is as below :

```
public class YourMarkerView  extends MarkerView {

    private TextView tvContent;
    private RelativeLayout mainbackground;


    /**
     * Constructor. Sets up the MarkerView with a custom layout resource.
     *
     * @param context
     * @param layoutResource the layout resource to use for the MarkerView
     */
    public YourMarkerView(Context context, int layoutResource) {
        super(context, layoutResource);
        tvContent = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvContent);
        mainbackground = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainbackground);

    }



    // callbacks everytime the MarkerView is redrawn, can be used to update the
    // content (user-interface)
    @Override
    public void refreshContent(Entry e, Highlight highlight) {
        if(e!=null && e.getData()!=null){
            Log.d("Yoyo",e.getData().toString());

            mainbackground.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(e.getData().toString().split(";")[1]));

            tvContent.setText("" + e.getData().toString().split(";")[0]);

            // this will perform necessary layouting
            super.refreshContent(e, highlight);
        }

    }

    private MPPointF mOffset;

    @Override
    public MPPointF getOffset() {

        if(mOffset == null) {
            // center the marker horizontally and vertically
            mOffset = new MPPointF(-(getWidth() / 2), -getHeight());
        }

        return mOffset;
    }
}
```

Below is code for Chart:

```
chart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
        chart.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f9f9f9"));
        chart.setDrawGridBackground(false);
        chart.setDrawBarShadow(false);
        chart.setHighlightFullBarEnabled(false);

        // draw bars behind lines
        chart.setDrawOrder(new CombinedChart.DrawOrder[]{
                CombinedChart.DrawOrder.BAR, CombinedChart.DrawOrder.SCATTER
        });

        chart.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false);
        chart.getAxisLeft().setEnabled(false);
        chart.getXAxis().setEnabled(false);

        Legend legend = chart.getLegend();
        legend.setEnabled(false);

        YourMarkerView mv = new YourMarkerView(myActivity, R.layout.custom_marker_view);
        // Set the marker to the chart
        mv.setChartView(chart);
        chart.setMarker(mv);
        chart.setDragEnabled(false);
        chart.setScaleEnabled(false);

        // force pinch zoom along both axis
        chart.setPinchZoom(false);

        // enable touch gestures
        chart.setTouchEnabled(true);
        CombinedData data = new CombinedData();

        data.setData(generateBarData());
        data.setData(generateScatterData());

        chart.setData(data);
        chart.invalidate();

private BarData generateBarData() {

        ArrayList<BarEntry> entries1 = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<BarEntry> entries2 = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int index = 0; index < count; index++) {
            entries1.add(new BarEntry(0, getRandom(25, 25)));

            // stacked
            entries2.add(new BarEntry(0, new float[]{getRandom(13, 12), getRandom(13, 12)}));
        }

        BarDataSet set1 = new BarDataSet(entries1, "Bar 1");
        set1.setColor(Color.rgb(60, 220, 78));
        set1.setValueTextColor(Color.rgb(60, 220, 78));
        set1.setValueTextSize(10f);
        set1.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);

        BarDataSet set2 = new BarDataSet(entries2, "");
        set2.setStackLabels(new String[]{"Stack 1", "Stack 2"});
        set2.setColors(Color.rgb(61, 165, 255), Color.rgb(23, 197, 255));
        set2.setValueTextColor(Color.rgb(61, 165, 255));
        set2.setValueTextSize(10f);
        set2.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);

        float groupSpace = 0.06f;
        float barSpace = 0.02f; // x2 dataset
        float barWidth = 0.45f; // x2 dataset
        // (0.45 + 0.02) * 2 + 0.06 = 1.00 -> interval per "group"

        BarData d = new BarData(set1, set2);
        d.setBarWidth(barWidth);

        // make this BarData object grouped
        d.groupBars(0, groupSpace, barSpace); // start at x = 0

        return d;
    }

    private ScatterData generateScatterData() {

        ScatterData d = new ScatterData();
        ArrayList<Integer> colors = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (String color : details.getSequenceColors()) {
        colors.add(Color.parseColor(color));
        }
        ArrayList<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<>();

        for (float index = 0; index < count; index += 0.5f)
            entries.add(new Entry(index + 0.25f, getRandom(10, 55),"title;"+colors.get(index)));

        ScatterDataSet set = new ScatterDataSet(entries, "Scatter DataSet");
        set.setDrawHorizontalHighlightIndicator(false);
        set.setDrawVerticalHighlightIndicator(false);
        set.setColors(colors);
        set.setScatterShape(ScatterChart.ScatterShape.CIRCLE);
        set.setScatterShapeSize(20f);
        set.setDrawValues(false);
        set.setValueTextSize(10f);
        d.addDataSet(set);

        return d;
    }
```

details.getSequenceColors is simple pojo contains the list of colors. For each point on Scatter Graph i am setting different colors. I am setting ScatterShape.CIRCLE color and Marker Background color same on Scatter Graph. As per Draw order I am drawing the bar graph first then the scatter one. Issue here i am facing is When i click on area where no scatter points exist the marker background color and nearest scatter point color is different and it highlights Bar graph datapoint as well. Its doesnt show the exact marker on Scatter points not sure why.  How can i make sure that the scatter Circle color and marker Background color will be always in sync for each data points?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by Using Custom ScatterDataSet Class:

```
public class MyScatterDataSet extends ScatterDataSet {
    static int currentIndex = 0;

    public MyScatterDataSet(List<Entry> yVals, String label) {
        super(yVals, label);
    }

    @Override
    public int getColor(int index) {
        int ret =super.getColor(currentIndex);
        currentIndex+=1;
        return ret;
    }
}
```